# Calculate average days between events?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table that includes:

```
user_id | event_time
```

How can I calculate the average days between events? To get something like:

```
days_diff | count
        1 | 100
        2 | 90
        3 | 20
```

A user may have 1 day between events, but may also have 3 days between to subsequent events. How can I count them in both buckets?

Sample data (note in this case the DAY DIFF is 0/1 but this is just a small subset of data)

```
user_id | event_time
82770 2015-05-04 02:34:53
1 2015-05-04 08:45:53
82770 2015-05-04 20:38:24
82770 2015-05-04 20:38:24
82770 2015-05-04 20:38:24
1 2015-05-05 09:31:42
82770 2015-05-05 13:33:36
82770 2015-05-05 13:33:53
1 2015-05-06 09:53:59
1 2015-05-06 23:31:18
1 2015-05-06 23:31:35
1 2015-05-07 12:31:41
82770 2015-05-07 16:01:16
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Added sample data to original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution without using a temporary table:

```
select daybetweenevents as days_diff,
   count(daybetweenevents) as count
from (select t1.user_id,
    t1.event_time,
    datediff(day, t1.event_time, min(t2.event_time)) as daybetweenevents
    from yourtable t1
    inner join yourtable t2
       on t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    and t1.event_time < t2.event_time
    group by t1.user_id, t1.event_time) temp
group by daybetweenevents
```

Comment: Hmm this does indeed work but not in the format I was hoping for.

it groups by user and then displays their average daydiff. I want the daydiff and the total # of events with that daydiff. When I try to rearrange and just group by daybetweenevents I get aggregates not allowed in GROUP BY

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF` and a correlated sub query to get previous date.

```
SELECT user_id, event_time, 
DATEDIFF((SELECT MAX(event_time) 
          FROM yourtable 
          WHERE event_time < a.event_time), event_time) AS days_diff
FROM yourtable AS a
```

Comment: This gets me by user - but I'm looking for a summary of "this many people had the event 2 days apart", "this many people had the event 6 days apart"

Answer (score 0):

I went with a temporary table of sorted user events to make the correlation lookup easier and handle users with more than two events.  This should get you the output you are asking for.

```
create table #tempOrderedUserEvents
(
id int identity (1,1),
userid int,
event_time datetime
)

insert into #tempOrderedUserEvents (userid, event_time)
select [user_id], event_time
from YourUserDataTable A
order by [user_id], event_time

select interval, count(*) as [count]
from
(
    select A.userid, datediff(day, A.event_time, B.event_time) as interval
    from #tempOrderedUserEvents A
    JOIN #tempOrderedUserEvents B on A.id+1 = B.id and A.userid = B.userid
) as Intervals
group by interval

drop table #tempOrderedUserEvents
```